# Display a message and perform actions on selected index changed asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I have a drop down list that allows an admin to assign a user to a role and it is supposed to automatically do so when the index is changed but unfortunately its not doing anything until I click a checkbox that is totally unrelated. Here is the code

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userName = Request.QueryString["user"];
    MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser(userName);

    ProfileCommon p = Profile.GetProfile(usr.UserName);

    var item = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedItem;

    switch (item.Value)
    {
        case "1":
            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(usr.UserName, "Builder") == false)//if the user is not already in the builder role then add them
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(usr.UserName, "Builder");//here we add the user into the builder role
                StatusMessage2.Text = "User has been added to the builder role";//Letting the admin know that the user was added to the role

                /* Creating a connection to write to a table in the default database */
                string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection conn = null;
                conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
                conn.Open();

                /* Here we execute the command and add a member into the table */
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {

                    string query = String.Format("INSERT INTO TestTable (testfirst, testlast, testaddr, testmail, testcomp) VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}','{4}')", p.fName, p.lName, p.Address, usr.Email, p.Company);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
 }
```

And here is where I make the DDL in the aspx page

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="0">Please select from below...</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Builder</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">Investor</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">Administrator</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Is there something I'm missing because I thought that it would automatically perform the tasks on selected index changed. Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the checkbox trigger a postback?

Comment: Yes it does. I think that's what I missed here. as @Freak_Droid said I just have to add an `AutoPostBack=true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `AutoPostback=true` In the drop down list. Without that does not fire the  `onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"`

I hope that help.

Comment: The event will fire when the form is posted.